# Write canvas in pdf and save it in storage android studio, doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, canvas, local-storage

i have a probleme, i want to create a pdf and save him in download path on the phone, but it seems like there is an error and i don't know how to figure it out.

Can anyone help me please ? (I already have the permission for access storage, i think :/ ).

This is my code -->

**fun createPdf**

```
fun createPdf(
    text: String,
    context: Context
) {
    val myPDFdocument = PdfDocument()
    val myPaint = Paint()
    val myPageInfo1 = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1240, 1754, 1).create()
    val myPage1 = myPDFdocument.startPage(myPageInfo1)
    val canvas = myPage1.canvas

    canvas.drawText(text, 40F, 50F, myPaint)
    myPDFdocument.finishPage(myPage1)

    val file = File(context.externalCacheDir!!.absolutePath, "/FirstPdf.pdf")
    try {
        myPDFdocument.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    myPDFdocument.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, here is the solution : (Principaly for android 11)

**fun createPdf**

```
val imageCollection = 
MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, "${commande}.pdf")
    put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
    put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 1)
}

val itemUri = resolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)
try {
    Toast.makeText(context, "salut toi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    resolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)?.also { uri ->
        resolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
            myPDFdocument.writeTo(outputStream)
        }
    }
    contentValues.clear()
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.IS_PENDING, 0)
    resolver.update(itemUri!!, contentValues, null, null)
    myPDFdocument.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```